# vlookup error in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have a two sheets in excel i need to compare the text from sheet with sheet 1 and return the relevant code and bring the result,but im getting n/ error

data in sheet1

```
AH  GOLDEN FOODS-BRAND  AAK
TW  TRTNI LLC CINCINNA  Felda, Cinci OH
HT  HUDSON TANK TERM    Hudson
ZJ  ID GLYCERINE    Cincinnati Plant
K7  KANSAS CITY CHEM.   Kansas City Plant
PX  P&G % KMTEX RMCO    KmTex
PN  P&G % PETER CREMER  Peter Cremer
SF  P&G % SUPERFLO  Superflo
71  SACRAMENTO PLANT    Sacramento Plant
RL  RAIL SCARM P&G CH   RAIL (Sacto)
SO  WESTWAY TERMINAL    Westway
CJ  CHEM STOLT HAVEN    Stolt
TQ  TWIN RIVERS TERM'L  TRT
*   All All
```

data in sheet2

```
GOLDEN FOODS-BRAND
TRTNI LLC CINCINNA
HUDSON TANK TERM
ID GLYCERINE
KANSAS CITY CHEM.
P&G % KMTEX RMCO
P&G % PETER CREMER
P&G % SUPERFLO
SACRAMENTO PLANT
RAIL SCARM P&G CH
WESTWAY TERMINAL
CHEM STOLT HAVEN
TWIN RIVERS TERM'L
All
```

if the data in sheet2 matches with sheet 1 it should return the code like AH.

=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A1:C14,1,FALSE)

Comment: And what happens instead? What error are you getting?

Comment: You need to use `Index` and `Match` functions. `Vlookup` only looks in the first column of the specified range.

Comment: i got n/a error using my formula jon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use Vlookup for a right-to-left search. You will need to combine `Index` and `Match` functions:

To return the value from first column:

```
=index(Sheet1!A1:A14,Match(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!B1:B14,False),1)
```

You cannot do this in VLOOKUP without re-arranging your data.  The VLOOKUP formula takes 3 arguments (required) and 1 optional.

[image]

`lookup_value` -- This is the key that you are searching for

`table_array`  -- This is the range/array in which the Lookup is performed. Vlookup searches for the `lookup_value` ONLY in the FIRST COLUMN of `table_array`.

`col_index_num` -- Specifies which column of `table_array` the return value will come from

`[range_lookup]` -- Optional, defaults to `True` which assumes that your table is sorted on the first column in ascending order and will return a near match if the exact value is not found. Since I usually do not make this assumption, nor do I want a "near match", I typically use `False` for this argument which forces an exact match.

If you want to do this with VLOOKUP, you will have to re-arrange your data so that the lookup value would be in column A:

```
GOLDEN FOODS-BRAND  AH    AAK
TRTNI LLC CINCINNA  TW    Felda, Cinci OH
HUDSON TANK TERM    HT    Hudson
ID GLYCERINE        ZJ    Cincinnati Plant
KANSAS CITY CHEM.   K7    Kansas City Plant
P&G % KMTEX RMCO    PX    KmTex
P&G % PETER CREMER  PN    Peter Cremer
P&G % SUPERFLO      SF    Superflo
SACRAMENTO PLANT    71    Sacramento Plant
RAIL SCARM P&G CH   RL    RAIL (Sacto)
WESTWAY TERMINAL    SO    Westway
CHEM STOLT HAVEN    CJ    Stolt
TWIN RIVERS TERM'L  TQ    TRT
```

Comment: hah, beat me to it :)

Comment: You **can't** do this with VLOOKUP without re-arranging your data.

Comment: is there any workaround that i can do this in vlookup

Comment: thanks all,understood how vlookup works and why vlookup wont work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  =INDEX(Sheet1!A1:A13, MATCH(A1,Sheet1!B1:B13 , False))
```

Comment: didnot get an exact result.

Comment: You need the `False` argument in the `Match` function to return an exact match.

Answer (score 0):

I often find that I need to 'normalize' data before I do vlookup. Difference in formatting might cause a mismatch.

To normalize, I copy existing columns (duplicate them) and then use this 'trick'

Step 1 - get rid of various formatting
1. Select one column you will be using to lookup the data
2. DATA tab -> Text to columns -> Delimited -> (REMOVE ALL CHECKMARKS) -> Click Finish

Step 2 - normalize to lower case and remove all spaces
1. Insert new column next to the `Step 1` column
2. use this formula `=LOWER(TRIM(A2))` (use actual cell number).

Then, make sure that you do lookup on `A` column - just make sure that lookup values are in the front of everything.

When you completed these steps on sheet1, you also need to normalize sheet 2.
Then, you can do vlookup using data from normalized columns.